# Getting the Base Price of an Item in NetSuite

Tags: c#, web-services, netsuite

For a given NonInventorySalesItem, I clearly see on the Netsuite website that a "base price" is set. But I cannot find it in any of the properties of an instance of NonInventorySalesItem.

I thought the pricingMatrix property should have it. Nope. It's null. And the base price is clearly set in this case at $69. So this has been my holy grail. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The "pricingMatrix" property has all the data I need.  The reason why it was null was that the bodyfieldsOnly property of SearchPreferences was set to true.

Comment: Thanks, @user79284. i want to know where can i set the SearchPreferences.